# Let $a_1,a_2,b_1$ and $b_2$ be elements in an integral domain $D$. Show that $a_1|b_1$ if and only if $a_2\mid b_2$

Tags: divisibility

We may assume that $a_1$ and $a_2$ are associated, and that $b_1$ and $b_2$ are associated.

So here is what I've got so far:

Lets assume that $a_1|b_1$. By definition, this is: $b_1=a_1\cdot c$ for some $c\in D$.

By associativity, $a_1=a_2\cdot u_1$ and $b_1=b_2\cdot u_2$, we can rewrite this as:

$b_2\cdot u_2=(a_2\cdot u_1)\cdot c$

Where $u_1$ and $u_2$ are units in $D$.

Now here is where I am stuck. I might be missing something related to units of groups, but if I could only get them to magically disappear from this equation I would have $a_2|b_2$. Any pointers?

Comment: Note that $u_2^{-1}\in D$.

Comment: Simply scale your final equation by $\,u_2^{-1}.\,$ Generally $\, c\mid ud\iff c\mid d\,$ when $u$ is a unit.

Comment: @BillDubuque So if I express it as $b_2=(a_2\cdot u_1)\cdot c\cdot u_2^{-1}$ this means that I can simply neglect the units? Sorry, divisibility is not my strong suit apparently. :(

Comment: You have $\,b_2 = a_2 (u_1 c\, u_2^{-1})\,$ so $\,a_2\mid b_2,\,$ since $\,u_1 c\, u_2^{-1}\in D.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Oh, that makes sense! Thank you :)